# Solving 500-Integration Error with Amazon API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a lambda instance, then used the 'automagic' button in lambda to create an http API gateway. I have modified the log output within the API Gateway instance, but not much else. When I call it within my application, I'm getting an intermittent error (API Gateway log):

```
{
    "requestId": "xxxx",
    "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "requestTime": "10/Jan/2020:18:47:08 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "routeKey": "/Current",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "35",
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "error response type": "INTEGRATION_FAILURE"
}
```

When this happens, it doesn't seem to be hitting the lambda instance at all (duh! integration failure!). Or at least there's nothing in the lambda log.

But if I reload the web page that makes the call a couple of times, the error no longer appears.

Does the lambda instance need to 'wake up'? I tried a 'pre-call' within my application, under the assumption that this was the case and it didn't seem to help.

What is happening and what can I do to avoid the blank screen my customer is seeing?

UPDATE: I have checked the permissions, and run the command necessary to make sure they are correct:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
  --statement-id [statement id] \
  --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
  --function-name [lambda function name] \
  --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
  --source-arn [source arn]
```

It didn't help.

Comment: No you don't need a wake up.have you tested lambda function without API gateway

Comment: Only through the internal testing. Is there a way to hit it from 'outside'? And, as I said, it's working after whatever wakes it up.

Comment: Might have to look at the lambda function to debug

Comment: OK - ran the Lambda function from AWS CLI and found no issues. So the error is not with the Lambda function.

Comment: amracel@ I have seen a few issue like these recently, most of them which were fixed by removing the existing integration and re-adding it. I know this may not be the optimal solution now, but HTTP APIs are still in beta. 

Also, have you tried using the original REST API with the same Lambda? Let me know if you are having any problems with that.

Comment: Odd! I don't seem to be able to delete it, either from the API Gateway end (because it was 'automatically initiated') or from the Lambda end. On the Lambda end, I click 'Delete', its status becomes 'Pending'. But when I refresh at any point, It's back to 'live'.

Comment: @SurajBhatia: I've created the REST interface and am having trouble getting it to work. But that may be just my missing parts of the setup. For some reason, the query string doesn't get passed, even though I've added the parameters to the get method.

Comment: @amracel If you are having trouble passing query strings, try testing with proxy integration and print out the event data in Lambda to verify. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Answer (score -1):

Did you by any chance configure an authorizer that's piped into the API Gateway?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is an answer to the OP's question. Could you please clarify your answer? Also, avoid phrasing your answers as questions.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I should've posted this as a comment under his post. Still getting used to StackOverflow, bit new here.